# FileUpload: selecting specific file types

Tags: asp.net, .net, file-upload

I am using a fileupload object on my user interface (.net). I would like it to select only specific file types when it searches for files and I would also like the path not be cleared out of it upon PostBack of the page. Any suggestions??

Comment: .net is capital and has more than 1 ui

Comment: Not clearing file path poses a potential security risk, and always can be overridden/forged on the client side. I would not pursue this as a goal.

Answer (score 0):

There are many file upload options that work in .NET.  For a .NET web project, I like to use Dean Brettle's NeatUpload, which is free, and can select specific types.  Unlike the built-in .NET FileUpload control, it also will show progress, which is a nice thing for users loading large files.

http://neatupload.codeplex.com/

Comment: I eventually used a regular expression validator to validate the file upload objects. I allowed it to look for strings that ended with .pdf, .jpg or .doc...Seems to work fine for me. Thanks for the suggestion though. I did download it and tested it out